# migration: post ownership lost through multiple migrations

Tags: bug, migration

When going through several migrations the user owning the post may loose the ownership. E.g. if user X has profiles on sites A and C but not B, and one of his posts on A is migrated to B and then to C, X looses the ownership of the post although he has a profile on C.

Here is an example:

- Post: [Master Equations and Operator Sum Form](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/11392/) (see [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/master-equations-and-operator-sum-form/11393#11393))
- User: [John Sidles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1519/john-sidles)

Comment: Community mods can fix such cases, but obviously an actual bugfix would be prefered.

Comment: @Raphael, they can't.

Comment: They have merged "grey" users with actual users on cs.SE before; is there a difference here?

Comment: @Raphael, the problem is there is no user to be merged, check the answer's owner.

Comment: That's why regular mods can't, but they can. It's amusing how reluctant you are to trust me when I say: they did it before. I guess it's more like assigning the answer to a user. Just ask them in TL.

Comment: @Raphael, by community mods I thought you mean us not SE mods. I will ask them, thanks. (It is amusing how much you interpret people's actions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple migrations aren't supported very well right now (or, well, at all beyond just moving the question over to another site).

I'm not sure if this is something we can fix or if there are any plans to do so any time soon, but in the meantime I associated the answer with the correct user.

Comment: Thanks Anna $ $